# PHP: open another PHP with array value

Tags: php, arrays, new-window

Is it possible to open another PHP file (print_array.php) passing $array via PHP function?

HTML:

```
<form method=post>
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="111">
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="222">
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="333">
<button type="submit" name="action" value="print">Print</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="add">Add New</button>
</form>
```

array[] is all checked, so, $array value is 111, 222, and 333.

Then, PHP function:

```
switch ($action) {
  case 'print': printing($_post['array']); break; /* open new window */
  case 'add': break; /* same window */
  case 'delete': break; /* same window */
  default: break;
}

function printing($array) {
  /* open print_array.php in a new window showing $array value */
}
```

And then, only if action=print, open print_array.php in a new window with $array value.

```
if (is_array($array)) {
  print_r($array);
} else {
  ...
}
```

The result in print_array.php would be

```
Array ( [0] => 111 [1] => 222 [2] => 333 )
```

I don't think **header("Location: print_array.php")** can pass array value.
Is there any good way to open another PHP page in a new window passing array value?

Comment: New window conditionally means that normally Javascript is involved not PHP. So I'd say the simple answer is "No." without going into too much detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the window using Javascript, use window.open() when the page loads.

To get the data to the new page, use _SESSION variables. When you get to the script with the swtich, use:

```
start_session(); 
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['array'];
```

On the new window (after you use header() to get to it, use:

```
start_session();
$array = $_SESSION['data'];
```

You will have access to the entire array in the new window.

Comment: I used session to keep array values and javascript to open new window.. worked well :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that PHP doesn't open windows and such.  What you are looking to do sounds like it needs to be achieved in HTML and/or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use javascript:

Firs declare your checkboxes to call a javascript function when clicked:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" onclick="myfunction(111)" value="111">
```

Then include the following in your page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function myfunction(number) {
          if (number == 111) {
              location.href="mypage.html";
          }
      }
 </script>
```

You can also use [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for this if you strictly want to go with PHP.

At the server end you can do `switch($_GET['array'])` and do your stuff. This way you would have to change your form declaration to

```
<form method=post action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

or

```
<form method=post action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```